# how can i hide the read more links in typo3 (7.6.23) using tx_news (6.1.1)

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I need to hide the more link in the news_list when cropMaxCharacters exceed the maximum characters in a news.
Is it possible via typoscript template setup?

This is my typoscript template for the news page.

```
plugin.tx_news.settings {
  startingpoint = 128
  list.paginate.itemsPerPage = 10
  cropMaxCharacters = 9999
}

lib.news = USER
lib.news {
  userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
  pluginName = Pi1
  vendorName = GeorgRinger
  extensionName = News
  controller = News
  settings =< plugin.tx_news.settings
  persistence =< plugin.tx_news.persistence
  view =< plugin.tx_news.view
}
lib.news_list < lib.news
lib.news_list {
  action = list
  switchableControllerActions.News.1 = list
}
lib.news_detail < lib.news
lib.news_detail {
  action = detail
  switchableControllerActions.News.1 = detail
}
[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news > 0]
  page.100.10.20 = COA
  page.100.10.20.10 < lib.news_detail
[else]
  page.100.10.20 = COA
  page.100.10.20.10 < lib.news_list
[end]
```

`cropMaxCharacters` is set that heigh, because i want to have all news with their complete text.

If there is a way to show all news on one page in detailed view i'd be interested in that, too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wishes can come true. but not so much with typoscript but with fluid.

As other extensions `ext:news` uses fluid templates which can be selectively(!) been replaced.

First add your pathes to the rootpathes:

```
plugin.tx_news {
  view {
    layoutRootPaths.10   = EXT:site_ext/Resources/Private/news/Layouts
    partialRootPaths.10  = EXT:site_ext/Resources/Private/news/Partials
    templateRootPaths.10 = EXT:site_ext/Resources/Private/news/Templates
  }
}
```

This will define alternative pathes for templates.

Now you need to copy the original Templates you want to modify from the subdir in the news extension into your folders.

Then you need to modify the templates.

The template for the list view could be found with the path `Templates/News/List.html`. the single news are rendered in the partial `partial/List/Item.html`. There you can find the usage of the viewhelper `f:format.crop` and the `more` link (look for the text "more-link")

If you want a complete listing of all news with full text you could replace the item partial with a copy of the template from the detail-view.